# ActiveRecord query for child objects in BEFORE_SAVE callback in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

`TypeLogistic` is a child of `Order`

I have a `before_save` callback on `Order`. In that `before_save` callback, I need to take different actions depending on if the `Order` has a specific child `TypeLogistic` or not.

Code:

```
class Order

  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    if self.type_logistics.where(type_of_logistics:"this type").present?
      ...
      # something that uses the data in the child type_logistic
    else 
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Is this somehow possible? Just playing around with the console:

```
o = Order.new({"type_logistics_attributes" => [{"type_of_logistics" => "this_type}]})
o.type_logistics
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<TypeLogistic id: nil, type_of_logistics: "this type" >]> 
o.type_logistics.where(type_of_logistics:"delivery")
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

I figured since the second statement from the console returned something, then perhaps there's a way to get the 3rd console to as well?

---

If this is entirely not possible, I'm open to other suggestions. Some other context:

1. I can't really use `after_commit` because there are things in `do_something` method that require detection of `new_record?` or `attribute_changed?` via `ActiveRecord::Dirty`, and that doesn't work `after_commit`
2. Incidentally, `after_save` should work, since it will allow me to do the above detection of `attribute_changed?` while also giving me object IDs to work with, but in production I've found that it does not. Perhaps it's because `do_something` contains delayed jobs that operate on different threads and can't find the required record or whatever

This is why I'm trying to make `before_save` work. If finding the child object is not possible, what I'll do is just parse the parameters for the required child object attributes. Not a big deal, just that won't be as easy as this.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: don't use callbacks, use some sort of service object which takes care of saving that order.
Callbacks will become messy and hard to debug, test and maintain.